# Read text between two coordinates

Tags: c++, text, coordinates, line

for my project i need to read a piece of text (from .txt file) between two line coordinates (ex. line 1, column 4 to line 1, column 9). And i also need to get the coordinates of a point after found a text with line.find (ex. found the character at line x, column y). I'am a beginner, i hope you help me. 
PS: i have saw the getLine function, but i don't think that works in my case. To find the character i have used this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream input;
    size_t pos;
    string line;

    input.open("/Users/francesco/Desktop/htmlprova.html");
    if(input.is_open())
    {
        while(getline(input,line))
        {
            pos = line.find("bello");
            if(pos!=string::npos) // string::npos is returned if string is not found
            {
                cout <<"Found!\n";
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: You can read a file line by line using `std::getline()` and then process contents of that line by (another) temporary instance of `std::istringstream`.

Comment: Please, provide a small sample input file to expose how input data is formatted.

Comment: c++ has no way of reading an arbitrary line from a file, you have to call `getLine`, count the number of lines you've read to find the right line

Comment: _"piece of text (from .txt file) "_, yet your code is referring to an HTML file. Which one is true?

Comment: @ZDF: For me a html file is simple text file.

Comment: HTML files are text files, but you cannot ignore the format. Please provide a sample file.